# the stability of ODE by studying the eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I'm trying to study the stability of systems of odes but i fail to find the steps of positive and zero eigenvalues; and in the case of negative and zero eigenvalues.

What is the procedure to follow if one of the eigenvalues is equal to zero and the rest are of a positive signs?

What is the procedure to follow if one of the eigenvalues is equal to zero and the rest are negative signs?

Comment: Are you dealing with linear time-invariant ODE's or are you looking at the eigenvalues of the Jacobian at equilibrium positions?

Comment: I'm looking to study the eigenvalues of jacobain matrix at equilibrium point

Comment: If you have already found an eigenvalue with positive real part, then this equilibrium is clearly unstable. When all your eigenvalues have non-positive real-parts you have two choices: either you can construct a Lyapunov function or you have to perform a center manifold reduction (http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Center_manifold ).

Comment: thanks for your answer  Evgeny; I just want to know what to do in the case where we obtain positive eigenvalue from the jacobian matrix.